# Is it weird to say "abnormal lessons"?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, word-meaning

I saw a commercial for a golf lesson and it was called "*abnormal* golf lesson". Although the lesson was not in English, they called it an abnormal golf lesson in English.

But I feel like it sounds a little awkward since "abnormal" kind of also means "weird" other than just "not normal".

Is it weird to call "abnormal" a lesson that's different from normal lessons?

Comment: You can say an abnormal lesson if it's different from what' s normal or usual.

Answer (score 2):

As you said, the adjective *abnormal* is mainly used with a negative shade in its meaning ([Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/learner/abnormal)):

> different from what is usual or expected, **especially in a way that is worrying, harmful or not wanted**: 
>   
>  *• Abnormal levels of sugar in the blood
>   
>  • They thought his behaviour was abnormal.
>   
>  • The ship was blown off course by abnormal weather conditions.*

Anyway, if you consider the origin of the word,

> *ab-* + *normal*; replacing *anormal*. 
>  Medieval Latin *anōrmālus*, variant of *anōmālus*,

*abnormal* can be used with its literal meaning, that is ([Dictionary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abnormal)):

> **not normal, average, typical, or usual**; deviating from a standard:
>   
>  *• **abnormal powers of concentration**;
>   
>  • an abnormal amount of snow; 
>   
>  • abnormal behavior.*